# ‎"They are guys who are capable of lifting 100kg." - each one of them or they together?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> ‎"They are guys who are capable of lifting 100kg."

I found this can be interpreted in two ways.

The first: every one of them is able to lift 100kg.

The other: they together can lift 100 kg.

Am i right?

Answer (score 4):

> "They are guys who are capable of lifting 100kg."

Technically, yes: the statement is ambiguous, and could be applied either to each one in the group, or to the group as a whole.  A native speaker, without any additional context, however, would be most likely to understand that the statement applied to the guys on an individual basis, not as a collective, i.e. that each one of the guys could lift 100 kg. independent of the others.

Comment: Agree - it's unusual to talk about how much multiple people can lift in tandem, and it would have been easy to rephrase as "they are a team of guys" if the statement was intended to refer to the group as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of "ambiguous" statements if you look for them. The reality is that *context* usually clears it up.

I like to use the example "*my father goes to work in a bowler hat*". It could sound like the bowler hat is the vehicle he travels in, but that's ridiculous, so nobody would ever think it meant that in everyday situations.

Could your example mean a group of guys who could lift 100kg collectively? Possibly, but no native English speaker would be likely to think that. "Guys" isn't specific enough to refer to a group and would be understood to mean *males in general* unless there was context that explicitly defined it otherwise.

Comment: And a further ambiguity in your example is, What does the prepositional phrase “in a bowler hat” modify? *Goes* or *work*?  As you say, ambiguities can very often be found if one willfully searches them out.